# python selenium - print xpath value

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code:

```
print browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/h1/div/small')
```

It prints `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x02915310>`
but I want it to print the actual value, which would be `0.00`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you for inner text:

```
print browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/h1/div/small').text
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to get the value:

```
print browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/h1/div/small').get_attribute("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you find an element you don't find the text of the element, but actually much more. It is a WebElement python object, which has a bunch of useful actions and values associated with it.

So the text of a the element is found by calling the `text` property is what you a currently looking for

browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/h1/div/small')

we get the WebElement with `browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/h1/div/small')`

but for the text we use `browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/h1/div/small').text`

and i am guessing you are going to want work with that as a float value, so ten its `float(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/h1/div/small').text)`

But there is much more you can look in a WebElement for other WebElements, for like

```
foo = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/p') 
bar = foo.find_element_by_xpath('/input')
baz = foo.find_element_by_xpath('button')
```

you can do things like `bar.get_attribute('name')` which will return a string or `bar.send_keys('good stuff')` or `baz.click()`

The documents can be found here

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement